# Ошибка «Error: connect ETIMEDOUT» в passport-vkontakte

Tags: node.js

На Node.JS создана авторизация через ВК.

Код самый обычный. Проблем заключается в том, что при 10 попытках авторизоваться (переход по ссылке /auth/vk) 7-9 раз из них получаются с такой ошибкой, остальные входит нормально.

Как быть?
Код смотрел - ничего не смог найти по проблеме.
Вытаскивал просто ссылку, по которой идет запрос - все работает без проблем.

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
  at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (F:\git\test\node_modules\passport-vkontakte\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:348:17)
  at F:\git\test\node_modules\passport-vkontakte\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:171:43
  at F:\git\test\node_modules\passport-vkontakte\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:176:18
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (F:\git\test\node_modules\passport-vkontakte\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:147:5)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
  at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1440:17)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at net.js:440:14
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Comment: У ВК в последнее время куча проблем, даже через браузер не всегда получается войти, так что не удивительно что ошибку подключения ловите

Comment: а запросы подряд летят? таймаут может спасет?

Comment: @deadulya возможно это так и есть.

Comment: @exec, ну так setTimeout(function(){sendrequest() }, 3000); =)

Comment: @deadulya хм, идея.

Answer (score 1):

Я не силен в nodejs, но возможно, запрос просто не получает ответа. Возможно поможет навешивание обработчика ошибки (errorHandler) который будет повторно отправлять запрос. По поводу отлова конкретно этой ошибки - посмотрите здесь: https://github.com/request/request/issues/636

Answer (score 0):

При использовании нативного JS при авторизации ВК не всегда отвечает ошибка timeOut, в последнее время ВК что то начал расстраивать.

Comment: Я не понял ваш ответ. Понял что всегда должна быть ошибка, и вы возмущены что иногда работает?